# Automatically folding #defines in vim

Tags: vim, scripting

I work with quite a bit of multi-platform C/C++ code, separated by common #defines (#if WIN, #if UNIX, etc).  It would be nice if I could have vim automatically fold the sections I'm currently not interested in when I open a file.  I've searched through the vim script archives, but I haven't found anything useful.  Any suggestions?  Places to start?

Answer (score 8):

Just add a folding region to your syntax
http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Syntax_folding_of_Vim_scripts#Syntax_definitions

```
:syn region myFold start="\#IF" end="\#ENDIF" transparent fold
:syn sync fromstart
:set foldmethod=syntax
```

Comment: This is why I love vim, haha.

Comment: I'm on vim 7.0, and I put the 3 lines at the end of my .vimrc, but I see some sections of my file getting arbitrarily folded. Can someone please post the exact steps to do the following: 
1. Fold based on the env varibles, e.g. if there is an #ifdef and the env variable is not set, then fold.
2. Fold all ifdefs(no matter how deep in hierarchy) and if you want to see them, you do a zo.

Comment: something that specific, you might be better served asking a new question, or posting on the vim mailing list (http://www.vim.org/community.php)

Answer (score 2):

To add to @hometoasts answer, you can add that command as a comment in the first ten or last ten lines of the file and vim will automatically use it for that file.

```
    /* vim: syn region regionName start="regex" end="regex": */
```

Comment: forgot about the "modelines". Perfect for a one-off

Answer (score 0):

A quick addition to Denton's addition: to use the new syntax rule with any C or C++ code, add it to a file at `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/c.vim` and `cpp.vim`. (`$VIMRUNTIME` is where your local Vim code lives: `~/.vim` on Unix.) Also, the values for `start` and `end` in the syntax definition are regular expressions, so you can use `^#if` and `^#endif` to ensure they only match those strings at the start of a line.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used forldmethod=marker and defined my own fold tags placed within comments.

this is for defining the characters that define the open and close folds. in this case open is "<(" and close is ")>" replace these with whatever you'd like.

```
set foldmethod=marker
set foldmarker=<(,)>
```

This is my custom function to decide what to display of the folded text:

```
set foldtext=GetCustomFoldText()
function GetCustomFoldText()
    let preline = substitute(getline(v:foldstart),'<(','<(+)','')
    let line = substitute(preline,"\t",'        ','g')
    let nextLnNum = v:foldstart + 1
    let nextline = getline(nextLnNum)
    let foldTtl = v:foldend - v:foldstart
    return line .  ' | ' . nextline . ' (' . foldTtl .  ' lines)>'
endfunction
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have a huge code base and so a large number of #defines. Each file has numerous #ifdef's
and most of the times they are nested. I tried many of the vim scripts but they always
used to run into some error with the code I have. So in the end I put all my defines in
a header file and included it in the file that I wanted to work with and did a gcc on it 
like this

gcc -E -C -P source.cpp > output.cpp

The -E command gets gcc to run only the pre-processor on the file, so all the unwanted
code within the undefined #ifdef's are removed. 
The -C option retains the comments in the file.
The -P option inhibits generation of linemarkers in the output from the preprocessor.